# What is the point of the second " ch = getchar(); "

Tags: c

```
int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    int len = 0;

    printf("Enter a message: ");
    ch = getchar();

    while (ch != '\n')
    {

        len = len + 1;
        ch = getchar();
    }
    printf("Your message was %d characters long\n", len);


    return 0;


}
```

I understand the first " ch = getchar(); " because that's reading the characters from the printf statement, but I don't understand the purpose of the 2nd " ch = getchar(); " in the while loop.

Comment: "that's reading the characters". It's reading **one character**. Read all about it in the [getchar man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar)

Answer (score 3):

This is trying to loop on reading characters until a newline is read, and it's just doing it in an odd way: normally I'd expect to see just one `getchar()` as part of the loop itself.

This would be a more customary way to write the same thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    int ch;            // note: not char!
    int len = 0;

    printf("Enter a message: ");

    while ( (ch = getchar()) != EOF  &&  ch != '\n')
       len++;

    printf("Your message was %d characters long\n", len);

    return 0;
}
```

We see a few changes here.

First, we see the `ch = getchar()` assignment *in the loop condition itself*: fetch a character, and as long as we're not done (however defined), keep going and keep counting.

But we also have to check for `EOF` - end of file - which signifies the end of input, so that test is done here as well. If you fail this test, the code will loop and loop and loop and loop because it will *never* get EOF. Always check for end of file!

**IMPORTANT**: You really must use an `int` variable to receive the return from `getchar()`, not a `char`. Surprise! The reason is that `EOF` is typically -1 ([EOF must be negative](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p3)), and [`getchar()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.1p2) returns either EOF or the next 'character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`' (normally, a value 0..255).  That is more values than can be stored in a plain `char`, so it is crucial to use an `int` instead of a `char` variable so you can be sure to detect EOF properly.

Also a trivial simplification of `len++` for `len = len + 1`.

The original loop is doing more or less the same thing, but without combining the get + check parts into one.

Comment: Alternatively, if one wanted the avoid the complex, assignment-containing condition, one could use: `while (1) { int ch = getchar(); if (ch == EOF || ch == '\n') break; ++len; }`

Answer (score 0):

To get all the characters that are typed before pressing enter. 
getchar reads only one character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The second `ch = getchar` reads one character, but it is inside of a while loop so `getchar()`will be read characters from input, one by one, until a line-break appears in the input. If you put in the input a string like this "Hello World" and press enter your program will read "Hello world\n" then the while loop increase by one the variable len to count the characters which you putted in the input and when `getchar`reads `'\n'` the while loop will end and the `printf()`shows you the length of your string